# Delphi ZXING Always Errors In Windows using Webcam

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, zxing, delphi-10.3-rio

This is my first question on this forum. I am trying to follow the rules, but if I transgress please just let me know and I'll fix it........ anyway onto my problem.....
I use Delphi Rad Studio 10.3.3 with all Patches applied.... I am not an expert but have a reasonable working knowledge of the environment.

I downloaded the latest version of the ZXING for Delphi native port and have incorporated into my project. Using code from the demo examples I am trying to read a barcode using the webcam for a proof of concept.
If I compile any of the provided demos for Windows that use decoding from the wecam, Windows complains with a message "Problem has caused Windows to Stop Working". All I am trying to do is put the ReadResult.Text into a memo.

Even if I carve out the GetImage method from the demo example that uses ttask to continually synchronize threads I still have the issue.

I have got as far as identifying that the issue exists when trying to access any of the ReadResult properties or methods after a call to ScanManager

After searching the internet for days (some of the articles have looked tantalisingly close) I have to finally admit that I need help and need to ask the question...... "what am I missing?"

Many Thanks

```
   unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types,
  System.UITypes,
  System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  System.Math.Vectors,
  System.Actions,
  System.Threading,
  System.Permissions,
  FMX.Types,
  FMX.Controls,
  FMX.Forms,
  FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Objects,
  FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Media,
  FMX.Platform,
  FMX.MultiView,
  FMX.ListView.Types,
  FMX.ListView,
  FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.ActnList,
  FMX.TabControl,
  FMX.ListBox,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.ScrollBox,
  FMX.Memo,
  FMX.Controls3D,
  ZXing.BarcodeFormat,
  ZXing.ReadResult,
  ZXing.ScanManager, FMX.Edit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Layout1: TLayout;
    StartButton: TButton;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Image2: TImage;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    imgCamera: TImage;
    lblScanStatus: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FScanManager: TScanManager;
    FScanInProgress: Boolean;
    FFrameTake: Integer;
    procedure GetImage();
  public
    { Public declarations }
    VideoCamera: TVideoCaptureDevice;
    procedure SampleBufferSync;
    procedure SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject; const ATime: TMediaTime);

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses

  FMX.DialogService;

{$R *.fmx}

 Var
 ThisFrameCount :Integer;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  AppEventSvc: IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
  VideoCamera := TVideoCaptureDevice
               (TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.GetDevicesByName(ComboBox1.Selected.Text));
  if (VideoCamera <> nil) then
  begin
    StartButton.Enabled := true;
    VideoCamera.Quality:=TVideoCaptureQuality.LowQuality;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
   VideoCamera.StopCapture;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
   if VideoCamera.State=tcapturedevicestate.Capturing then
      begin
       Formdeactivate(nil);
       Canclose:=False;
       application.ProcessMessages;
      end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  DeviceList: TCaptureDeviceList;
  i: integer;
begin
  ThisFrameCount:=0;
  lblScanStatus.Text := '';
  DeviceList := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.GetDevicesByMediaType
(TMediaType.Video);
  for i := 0 to DeviceList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(DeviceList[i].Name);
    ComboBox1.ItemIndex:=0;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if videocamera <> nil then
      begin
        VideoCamera.StopCapture;
        StartButton.Text := 'Start';
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject; const ATime: TMediaTime);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,     SampleBufferSync);//GetImage); Commented out as this methodology seemed     even worse. Left the routine in for further investigation if needed
  //Resize the image so the video to be buffered on its original size.
  Image1.Width:=Image1.Bitmap.Width;
  Image1.Height:=Image1.Bitmap.Height;
end;

procedure TForm1.SampleBufferSync;
Var
  ReadResult: TReadResult;
  ScanManager: TScanManager;
  Bitmap:TBitMap;
  CheckResult : String;
begin
  bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  Inc(ThisFrameCount);
  VideoCamera.SampleBufferToBitmap(Bitmap, true);
  Image1.Bitmap:= Bitmap;
  CheckResult:='';
  ReadResult:=Nil;
  // Only want every 5th frame prsed for decoding
  if ThisFrameCount >  5 then
     begin
      ScanManager := TScanManager.Create(TBarcodeFormat.auto, nil);
       try
        Image2.Bitmap:=Bitmap;   // This just copies to a different TImage so I coud be sure it wasnt a different issue
        ReadResult:=ScanManager.Scan(Bitmap);
        //PROBLEM IS HERE
        if ReadResult <> nil then MEMO1.Lines.Add(ReadResult.Text);        // <-- ALWAYS Windows throws exception "Problem has caused Windows to Stop Working
                                             // Throws this error wwhen     tring to access ANY property or Method of ReadResult EG ToString
                                             // Remove this line and it     runs just fine..... but alas no barcode number which defeats the purpose
      finally
        freeandnil(ScanManager);
        Freeandnil(ReadResult);
        BitMap.Free;
        ThisFrameCount:=0;
      end;
    end;
end;


procedure TForm1.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (VideoCamera <> nil) then
  begin
    if (VideoCamera.State = TCaptureDeviceState.Stopped) then
    begin
      VideoCamera.OnSampleBufferReady := SampleBufferReady;
      VideoCamera.StartCapture;
      StartButton.Text := 'Stop';
    end
    else
    begin
      VideoCamera.StopCapture;
      StartButton.Text := 'Start';
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Caption := 'Video capture devices not available.';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetImage;
var
  scanBitmap: TBitmap;
  ReadResult: TReadResult;

begin
  VideoCamera.SampleBufferToBitmap(imgCamera.Bitmap, True);

  if (FScanInProgress) then
  begin
    exit;
  end;

  { This code will take every 4 frame. }
  inc(FFrameTake);
  if (FFrameTake mod 4 <> 0) then
  begin
    exit;
  end;

  scanBitmap := TBitmap.Create();
  scanBitmap.Assign(imgCamera.Bitmap);
  ReadResult := nil;

// There is bug in Delphi Berlin 10.1 update 2 which causes the TTask and
// the TThread.Synchronize to cause exceptions.
// See: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16377?jql=project%20%3D%20RSP%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20affectedVersion%20%3D%20%2210.1%20Berlin%20Update%202%22%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC

  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      try
        FScanInProgress := True;
        try
          ReadResult := FScanManager.Scan(scanBitmap);
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            TThread.Synchronize(nil,
              procedure
              begin
                lblScanStatus.Text := E.Message;
              end);

            exit;
          end;
        end;

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin

            if (length(lblScanStatus.Text) > 10) then
            begin
              lblScanStatus.Text := '*';
            end;

            lblScanStatus.Text := lblScanStatus.Text + '*';
            if (ReadResult <> nil) then
            begin
             // Memo1.Lines.Insert(0, ReadResult.Text);
            end;

          end);

      finally
        ReadResult.Free;
        scanBitmap.Free;
        FScanInProgress := false;
      end;

    end);

end;


end.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For a "why isn't this code working?" you really need to add to your q to provide a full [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in other words something that readers could copy/paste into their IDE to test for themselves.  At the moment, f.i, we don't know how `VideoCamera` is declared and initialised.  Also, have you tried doing the scan in the app's main thread?  I realise you wouldn't want to do it that way "for real" but is would remove one layer of complication for the time being.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response  Shall do. Ill clean up redundant stuff from my testing and post up. Will be posted Here within the hour. 
King Regards.

Comment: No worries & no hurry.  Btw, it's good to see a new contributor reacting to comments - many don't.

Comment: Thanks @MartynA. That's amazing.......... I figure you either need help or you don't, so wouldn't want to waste anyone's time....... That being the case, I'm especially grateful being a new contributor and all. I've edited the code above for a full version. I never intended for anyone to see this in it's current state. I don't usually throw things on a form like this....... it's a sign of my frustration..... not my "Style". To Reproduce just run and try to scan a barcode with the webcam. It will error rather than update the memo. BTW... do you also want me to upload the ZXing.Delphi-v_3.0 Zip?

Comment: Delphi ZXING can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi

Comment: Just noticed your suggestion re using main thread......... I hadn't done so. I haven't explicitly used threads (I'm usually involved with DB transactions and haven't needed to). I was under the impression that the video handling needed to be done in this way (SampleBufferSync) to intercept the video camera device. Am I wrong? Is there an alternate way of knowing when a new frame is received using the main thread of the app? The only event I can see for camera component is OnSampleBuffer event.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much experience with threads, so this is not elegant but I thought I'd post as an answer in case it assists anyone else with better knowledge that I to progress. The below code works without AV's. Note that the hit rate for decoding the barcode will be entirely dependent on how quickly and accurately your camera can auto focus and you'll need a reasonable resolution camera. I couldn't get a scan result in LowRes.

The Issues were numerous. So I'll Briefly go through the main ones:

1 When using firemonkey use FMX.Graphics.TBitmap; (I was also stupidly referencing objects not correctly instanced.... Sign of fatigue :-(  )

2 Keep Interactions with Controls on the form to a minimum.

3 Most Significantly the only way I could get this to work as a prototype was to Create a bitmap that I could access globally from within the unit for each video frame. Then I needed a timer to run every [x] ms to act as a worker to process, but critically (for reasons unknown to me) I had to create a separate procedure to decode the barcode and call that from a TTASK in the OnTimer event. If don't use the TTASK then you will get AV's. Remember that to use TTask you need to add System.Threading to your "Uses" clause.

Anyway I hope this helps someone else out.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, ZXing.BarcodeFormat,
  ZXing.ReadResult,
  ZXing.ScanManager, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Objects, FMX.Media, System.Threading;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CameraComponent1: TCameraComponent;
    imgCameraView: TImage;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    ComboBox2: TComboBox;
    Start: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    lblScanStatus: TLabel;
    ScanTimer: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CameraComponent1SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
      const ATime: TMediaTime);
    procedure StartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScanTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure GetImage;
    procedure GetBarcode;
  public
    { Public declarations }

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

 Var
 ThisFrameCount :Integer;

  MyBitmap:FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;

procedure TForm1.CameraComponent1SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
  const ATime: TMediaTime);
begin
   TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, GetImage);

end;


procedure TForm1.GetImage;

begin
  CameraComponent1.SampleBufferToBitmap(imgCameraView.Bitmap, True);
  If ScanTimer.Enabled=True then MyBitmap:= imgCameraView.Bitmap;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetBarcode;
Var
    ReadResult: TReadResult;
    ScanManager: TScanManager;

begin
  ScanManager := TScanManager.Create(TBarcodeFormat.auto, nil);
   try
     try
       ReadResult:=ScanManager.Scan(MyBitmap);
       if ReadResult <> nil then
          begin
            MEMO1.Lines.Add(ReadResult.Text);
            ScanTimer.Enabled:=False;
          end
       else
        begin
          //mybitmap.SaveToFile('D:\Documents\DelphiProjects\WinSoftTest2\'+inttostr(Random(10000000))+'.jpg');
          memo1.lines.add ('No Barcode Fount Yet');
        end;
     except
      on E : Exception do
     begin
       ShowMessage('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName);
       ShowMessage('Exception message = '+E.Message);
       exit;
     end;
     end;
   finally
     freeandnil(ScanManager);
     Freeandnil(ReadResult);


   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScanTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TTask.Run(
        procedure
          begin
            getbarcode;
          end);
end;

procedure TForm1.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CameraComponent1.active then
    begin
      CameraComponent1.active:=False;
      CameraComponent1.Quality:=(TVideoCaptureQuality.MediumQuality);
      Start.Text:='Start';
      ScanTimer.enabled:=False;
    end
    else
    begin
     CameraComponent1.Quality:=(TVideoCaptureQuality.MediumQuality);
     CameraComponent1.active:=True;
      Start.Text:='STOP';
      ScanTimer.enabled:=True;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  DeviceList: TCaptureDeviceList;
  i: integer;
begin
  ThisFrameCount:=0;
  lblScanStatus.Text := '';
  DeviceList := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.GetDevicesByMediaType
    (TMediaType.Video);
  for i := 0 to DeviceList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(DeviceList[i].Name);
    ComboBox1.ItemIndex:=0;
  end;
end;

end.
```